How do I track and kill all processes spawned by running a script without knowing the names of the subprocesses?
I have a Bash wrapper script that launches a complex modeling script, which in turn launches multiple subprocesses and scripts of its own. I want to figure out how to track all processes that are spawned by one run of the modeling script so as to kill them all when certain criteria are met.
For example, my wrapper script called pipeline_runner.sh does the following:
#!/bin/bash

# Some set up of the script ...

./monitor_job.sh ... arguments TBD ... &

script_path="path/to/bash/script"

chmod u+x "$script_path"
"$script_path"

# ...

Each run of pipeline_runner.sh will start an instance of monitor_job.sh in the background to monitor the specific run of path/to/bash/script launched by that run of pipeline_runner.sh. When some arbitrary condition defined in monitor_job.sh is met, it should be able to kill that specific run of path/to/bash/script, together with all processes directly or indirectly launched by it.
The multiple other processes launched by a run of path/to/bash/script are many and variable, so I am trying to figure out how to capture every script that is spawned from running this into some sort of group or list and be able to kill them all when needed. Killing just the initial $script_path process is insufficient because all that script's subprocesses will survive.
Important secondary goals are:

to make this dynamic so that it doesn't depend on which script is designated by $script_path. This means I can't just hard code specific command names to look for.

to perform the monitoring in a separate script (monitor_job.sh) as described, not directly in pipeline_runner.sh.


How can I track all the processes launched by the modeling script so as to be able to kill them all at need?

I'm not sure how you would do it from a shell script, but if you can run pipeline_runner.sh in its own process group, you can kill the entire pgroup.

monitor_job.sh should also start $script_path, or at least pipeline_runner.sh should start script_path first, then pass the process ID (available from $PID) as an argument to monitor_job.sh. The process ID isn't as reliable, as there's always the chance that the process could die and a new process gets the recycled process ID without you noticing. A parent process, however, always gets notified directly when one of its children exits.

Since you tag Linux, I'm inclined to look in the direction of Linux cgroups.  SystemD uses that facility for pretty much exactly what you describe. I am not enough of an authority on CGroups to recommend details, however.

In fact, although it's not really a programming answer, you might be able to achieve what you want by using SystemD itself, by launching your pipeline_runner.sh as a user-level service unit.

You probably want to look at the Parent Process ID (PPID) to figure out what it was launched from.  Any time I have wanted to kill groups of processes spawned by a Bash session, I've just used grep to search for the shell's PID in the output of ps showing the PPID field.  All the sub-processes will normally share the same PPID.

kill -- -$$ will terminate the whole process group.
For example, in the following script we spawn 2 subprocesses, sleep 15 and sleep 30, then we could have various other tasks to run (in this case the sleep 5) and since we meet our exit criteria we can kill the whole process group.
#!/bin/sh
echo "Parent pid $$"
sleep 15 &
echo "child 1 pid $!"

sleep 30 &
echo "child 2 pid $!"

sleep 5
echo "criteria met"
kill -- -$$

If we run this with bash test.sh ;  ps -ef | grep sleep, we get:
$ bash test.sh ;  ps -ef | grep sleep
Parent pid 87546
child 1 pid 87547
child 2 pid 87548
criteria met
Terminated: 15
  501 87595   789   0  2:08PM ttys007    0:00.00 grep sleep

We observe therefore that the subprocesses have been killed as well.
The problem with this approach is that if ctrl+c was entered straight after my execution, we would get:
$ bash test.sh ;  ps -ef | grep sleep
Parent pid 88352
child 1 pid 88353
child 2 pid 88354
^C
  501 88353     1   0  2:10PM ttys007    0:00.00 sleep 15
  501 88354     1   0  2:10PM ttys007    0:00.00 sleep 30
  501 88391   789   0  2:10PM ttys007    0:00.00 grep sleep

This means that the various subprocesses would continue to run as orphans (adopted by the init process).
To address this issue we could use trap, and change our script to:
#!/bin/sh

trap "trap - SIGTERM && kill -- -$$" SIGINT SIGTERM EXIT

echo "Parent pid $$"

sleep 15 &
echo "child 1 pid $!"

sleep 30 &
echo "child 2 pid $!"

sleep 5
echo "criteria met"
exit 0

Normal execution would remain the same because exit 0 will be caught by trap and in turn kill -- -$$ would be executed as before.
Now if we run our script and enter ctrl+c straight after execution, this time around we get:
Parent pid 91578
child 1 pid 91579
child 2 pid 91580
^CTerminated: 15
  501 91590   789   0  2:18PM ttys007    0:00.00 grep sleep

where we see that subprocess have been killed as well.

Fantastic, thanks so much for the tutorial! This is exactly what I'm looking for.
